# Using Python how to download data of all the pages of a webpage that has the same link for all pages

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to download all the entries in the table as shown on this webpage - https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in/Portal/AuctionList
There are buttons to load next entries in the table but the link of the webpage remains same.
I want to download all the data in Python, I tried the following:

```
pd.read_html(link)
```

which results in a list containing the first 30 results in the table and another item with all 30 results combined. The default setting on the page to show the first 30 results only. How can I get data from all the following pages as well?

Answer (score 0):

i made enumareration on page

1. when you click on page 2 you actually making a post request to server see the curl request below

`curl "https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in/Portal/SearchAuctionGrid?page=2&Paging=True&pageSize=30&TabViewType=0&UnitId=0" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Origin: https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in/Portal/AuctionList" --data-raw "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest"`

so just make a post request to
`https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in/Portal/SearchAuctionGrid?page=2&Paging=True&pageSize=30&TabViewType=0&UnitId=0`

with this header
`X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`
and with this body
`X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

2. for the item count on page

make a post request to this url
https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in/Portal/SearchAuctionGrid

with this header

`X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

and with this data

`PageSize=50&UnitId=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to load the data from multiple pages into pandas dataframe:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://udhonline.rajasthan.gov.in/Portal/SearchAuctionGrid"

params = {
    "page": "1",
    "Paging": "True",
    "pageSize": "30",
    "TabViewType": "0",
    "UnitId": "0",
}

dfs = []
for page in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    params["page"] = page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.post(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser"
    )
    for t in soup.select("table:not(:has(table))"):
        dfs.append(pd.read_html(str(t))[0].T)

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                                     0                                                  1                                    2                                             3                                           4                       5                                                  6
0         AROGYA NAGAR RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 220 [9263]                          Scheme Name: Arogya Nagar                 Property Number: 220  EMD Deposit Start Date: 01-Jun-2021 08:00 AM  EMD Deposit End Date: 06-Jun-2021 11:59 PM    EMD Deposit Ends In:  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
1         AROGYA NAGAR RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 220 [9263]                          Scheme Name: Arogya Nagar                 Property Number: 220  EMD Deposit Start Date: 01-Jun-2021 08:00 AM  EMD Deposit End Date: 06-Jun-2021 11:59 PM    EMD Deposit Ends In:  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
2         AROGYA NAGAR RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 220 [9263]                          Scheme Name: Arogya Nagar   Property Area: 2118.32 Square Feet          Bid Start Date: 03-Jun-2021 10:00 AM          Bid End Date: 07-Jun-2021 11:00 AM            Bid Ends In:  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
3         AROGYA NAGAR RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 220 [9263]                          Scheme Name: Arogya Nagar   Property Area: 2118.32 Square Feet          Bid Start Date: 03-Jun-2021 10:00 AM          Bid End Date: 07-Jun-2021 11:00 AM            Bid Ends In:  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
4         AROGYA NAGAR RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 220 [9263]                          Scheme Name: Arogya Nagar              Usage Type: Residential                   EMD Amount (Rs.): 211900.00                    View Details Participate                     NaN  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
5         AROGYA NAGAR RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 220 [9263]                          Scheme Name: Arogya Nagar              Usage Type: Residential                   EMD Amount (Rs.): 211900.00                    View Details Participate                     NaN  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
6          CHANAKYAPURI RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 14 [9262]                          Scheme Name: Chanakyapuri                  Property Number: 14  EMD Deposit Start Date: 01-Jun-2021 08:00 AM  EMD Deposit End Date: 06-Jun-2021 11:59 PM    EMD Deposit Ends In:  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...
7          CHANAKYAPURI RESIDENTIAL PLOT NO. 14 [9262]                          Scheme Name: Chanakyapuri                  Property Number: 14  EMD Deposit Start Date: 01-Jun-2021 08:00 AM  EMD Deposit End Date: 06-Jun-2021 11:59 PM    EMD Deposit Ends In:  Assessed Property Value as per Bid Start Price...

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]